# I can't find the pass with foam

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-passes

I render a scene in Multilayer EXR sequence (Cycles). After I've combined the passes together everything is OK, but there the foam is missing. I've checked all the passes, and I don't see pass with foam.

#### Combined pass:

[image]

#### Composite:

[image]

**Math:** `((DiffuseDir + DiffuseInd) * DiffuseCol) + ((GlossDir + GlossInd) * GlossCol) + ((TransDir + TransInd) * TransCol)`

#### Ocean shader:

[image]

How can I get the foam for final composite?

Comment: How did you create the foam? If you used an emission shader, it would be in the emit pass (for example).

Comment: @JtheNinja  I'm not sure in what pass must be foam. I check the foam, in the ocean modifer settings, so I created a layer of foam. Then I used this layer using a node "attribute", while working with the ocean shader.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin What shader(s) did you plug the attribute node into?

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, i did.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks for your ideas yesterday - deleted my answer after I've realized it has nothing to do with nuke.

Comment: How about creating a material for the foam only, instead of integrating it with the water and creating a single complex material (Maybe even use the foam attribute to make a material that is all transparent but the foam... to keep the compositing simple).  Make a render layer with the water material and everyting else and a second layer with the foam. Take both in Nuke and work your magic.

Comment: Can you post a reduced blend file with just the ocean mesh? Also, can you remove any unnecessary nodes (There's a whole group top right that is not connected to any shader node, adding extra confusion to the node tree).

If you're sure the foam material is on a layer that is contributing to the Combined pass, then it has to do with the Emission or Environment passes which you are currently not combining in your compositing process.

Comment: The "foam" in the beauty render looks like it's more of a reflection of the light to me.  I'm coming from C4D, so I'm not sure about the names for the different Blender passes, but it'd be in something like "material specular" "material reflection" or maybe even "gloss" or "clearcoat."  A C4D "Environment" is different than a Blender one, but whatever the Blender equivalent for fake-environmental-reflections-from-an-HDRI-probe is called -- would be another candidate.